# How do I get the meta-data of a video file?

Tags: video, metadata

How can I get metadata, such as frame rate, resolution, audio and video bitrate, from a video file? Can this data be obtained from players like VLC and Media Player Classic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most players will have a way of giving this information. It may also be provided by the OS, depending on which one you are using (Windows 7 shows it in the status pane).

In any case, what you can do is to install a shell-extension like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to give you this information on demand.

Comment: I use command line medainfo

Answer (score 15):

With [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) comes [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#toc-Main-options)

```
$ ffprobe -show_data -hide_banner xyz.mp4 
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'xyz.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-04-26T19:36:24.000000Z
    com.android.version: 8.0.0
  Duration: 00:00:51.81, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14257 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 13936 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24.58 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 270
      creation_time   : 2017-04-26T19:36:24.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-26T19:36:24.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Answer (score 4):

I did use older versions of Super software for this

It has come to my attention that Super Software has malware bundled with the software so there is a better alternative called [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) which does the same thing. Once installed right click on the video file and select MediaInfo. When it opens select View>Tree to see all the information.

.

[image]
.

Comment: used to be popular, but got bundled with malware at some point. https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/stay-away-from-erightsofts-super-video-converter-full-of-malware.415697/  and somebody recently pointed out "you cant choose to NOT install this[malware]"

Comment: perhaps you could put an old version on archive.org   The oldversion website used to be good

Comment: 'super' and mediainfo don't do the same thing. Mediainfo provides info,  'super' was often used for converting video files and also provided info.

Comment: You can say that both pieces of software do what the user wants, but to say that they do the same thing is ambiguous and unclear, as it sounds like a broader statement.

Comment: An answer should answer a question, but if an answer e.g. says windows was invented in 1998 it sounds like they are saying that windows was invented in 1998, not that oh the question only asked about a particular windows version so the answer just referred to that particular windows version.  And those unfamiliar with windows pre 1998 may think you aren't just talking about a particular version. Similarly, if  a question asked about win7, and an answer says windows existed long before 1998. If somebody interpreted that in the specific way you suggest then it would be wrong.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this!  MediaInfo just helped me find meta data that I needed to prove tampering happened.

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that the answer that advices installing the SUPER program from http://www.erightsoft.com, that the free version comes bundles with a bunch of adware programs, like browser toolbars, surfing adds and whatnot. What worse is you cant choose to NOT install this bullshit and the installer dont mention anything about this except borrowed deep down in the usage aggreement (you have to skip past tons of legal mumble jumble to get to the part that explains that the install will install browser toolbars and various add programs on your pc).

I recommend not download or installing this adware program. With such practices in the free version I wouldnt want to support the company with the paid version, let alone trust them.

Comment: don't say "above mentioned...program" (super by erightsoft), when the answer above may not mention it..(right now the answer above your does not mention it). An answer mentioning t may be elsewhere in the thread, or the answer may even be removed as it mentions a program full of malware. As of wrting, the accepted answer is above yours and that's fine. It mentions a good program.

Comment: @barlop Then how do you suggest I refer to above mentioned program Super? (im honestly interested knowing how to do it correctly). The Super program by erightsoft is filled with adware, surf toolbars and all kinds of nasty crap that silently gets installed on your pc during installation. And you can not select to NOT install it (and as mentioned you dont even get notified about it). I think a stern warning about that program is very warranted. The only reason I discovered this was during the installation my anti-malware program blocked those installations and notified me about it.

Comment: @barlop I edited my answer, is it better to your liking now?

Comment: yes I stated the issue with what you wrote and you fixed it, so it's better now

Answer (score 1):

An answer mentions mediainfo windows "shell extension". I've often used mediainfo command line in windows, and sometimes the GUI version, which does indeed have a shell extension.

Mediainfo exists for windows or linux.. here is an example image, using the command line version.

[image]

`ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4`  also shows some info that may be relevant.

I use mediainfo a lot to show the container codec, the video codec, and the audio codec.  And you see frame rate and bit rate.

Comment: This is the standard solution. Also, both mediainfo and ffmpeg come with all Debian-derived Linux distributions. Double this!