# How to retrieve codecs informations in CLI on VLC?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, video-codecs

Is there a way to retrieve codecs information in command line using VLC ?

I want the same output as what we get with "Ctrl + j" when a video is loaded.

I found only solutions using third programs :

[Solution using MediaInfo](https://superuser.com/questions/1476737/type-of-audio-codec-being-played-in-vlc)

[Solution using ffprobe from ffpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/240604/how-do-i-get-the-meta-data-of-a-video-file)

Comment: it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is :
It's not possible. A third application is needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).